# Relations between the Fourier coefficients and the Taylor coefficients of the function $e^{\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^2}$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, power-series

Let $\displaystyle f(z)=e^{\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^2}$, $z\in \overline{\mathbb D}\setminus\{1\}$.
  Then the Taylor series $ f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$
 for $f$ diverges everywhere on $\mathbb T$ because $ a_n\geq 4ne$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. On the other hand, 
 the Fourier series of its boundary function
 $$\Phi(t)=\begin{cases}   f(e^{it}) & \text{if $t\notin \{2k \pi: k\in \mathbb Z\}$}\\
0& \text{if $t\in \{2k \pi: k\in \mathbb Z\}$}.\end{cases}$$
converges  everywhere  as $\Phi\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and is  even flat at each point $2k \pi, k\in \mathbb Z$.
Now my question: are there any relations between the Fourier coefficients of $\Phi$ and the Taylor coefficients of $f$?

Comment: I don't think you can expect much along these lines. The Fourier coefficients are the same as the Taylor coefficients when you have better boundary behavior ($f\in H^p$, say), so that would be the natural connection to hope for, but obviously you don't have it here.

Comment: Moreover if you define $f(1) = 0$ then $f$ is not even continuous at $z = 1$.